# Why is my Swift 3 encode running away?

Tags: swift, decode, encode

I've got a Swift class that has some "var"s that are primitive integer values and some that that are arrays of primitive integer values, or arrays of structs like CMTime.  When I do a NSKeyedArchiver.archiveRootObject on the object, if I restrict the encode to the integer values, [CMTime], and the smallest of the integer arrays, everything works fine.  (I can encode, then decode, and verify the equality of the contents.)
What is puzzling, is that encoding a [UInt16] that the debugger understands has fewer than 100M members, causes the app's memory allocation during encoding to increase to 4Gb, then 8Gb, then 12Gb (where I hit STOP).
Is there some problem with my use of coder.encode(aSwiftArray, forKey:"aKey"), where it works sometimes, but not others?

```
typealias WordSize = UInt16
class PixelHistogram :NSObject, NSCoding {
    var pixelCount:Int = 0
    var timeAtFrame: [CMTime] = [] // CMTime for each frame
    var pixelVsDelta: [UInt] = [] // 256x256 histogram of pixel vs DeltaPixel
    var histPixel:[WordSize] = [] // histogram of Y at each pixel [pixelCount][256]
}
// Initializing the various arrays...
histPixel = [WordSize](repeating: 0, count: 256*pixelCount)
pixelVsDelta = [UInt](repeating: 0, count: 256*256)

required convenience init?(coder aDecoder:NSCoder){
self.init()
timeAtFrame = aDecoder.decodeObject(forKey:Slot.timeAtFrame.rawValue ) as! [CMTime]
pixelVsDelta = aDecoder.decodeObject(forKey:Slot.pixelVsDelta.rawValue) as! [UInt]
    func encode(with coder:NSCoder)
    coder.encode(timeAtFrame, forKey: Slot.timeAtFrame.rawValue)        
    coder.encode(pixelVsDelta, forKey: Slot.pixelVsDelta.rawValue)
    }
```

Comment: [Edit] your question with relevant code.

Comment: show the code upload relevant sample if needed

Answer (score 0):

A possible answer to the memory runaway while encoding histPixel is that encodeObject is converting each UInt16 value in the array to an NSNumber. I had assumed that the encoding was just using encodeBytes behind the scenes.